# IconButton form material design not showing up in iOS

Tags: reactjs, button, redux, material-ui

I'm using [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) with react/redux/webpack. Where my [IconButton](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-button) is not showing up in **iOS** (haven't looked in Android, but checked on Safari and Chrome on iOS). The Icons are showing up on Desktop but not on iOs (mobile).

```
<a href={`http://maps.google.com/?q=${building.street}, ${building.zip} ${building.city}`} target="_blank">
   <IconButton style={style} tooltip="Google Maps"> <Direction color="#00AEDB"/> </IconButton>
</a>
```

#### Any Idea why it is not showing up in iOS?

For example the following RaisedButton is visible *correctly* on iOS and Desktop:

```
<RaisedButton label="Einloggen" type="submit" backgroundColor="#8ec127" className="card-margin" icon={<VerifiedUser />}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

My fault!

use `iconStyle` instead of `style`.

```
// Solution:
const styles = {navIcon: {width: 25, height: 25},..}
iconStyle{styles.navIcon}
```